# Merging postcode sector polygons into larger territories in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, shapefile, dissolve

I'm building a basic web-based mapping tool for business use, to be used as a demo to show that we need one but managers don't know it yet!

So far I've built a HTML page displaying an OpenLayers OSM base layer. I've been supplied with some postcode sector polygons in shapefile format that I'm wanting to merge into our business territories (wards, districts etc.).

Aims were to plot these as layers on top of OSM that the user can switch between etc.

Using QGIS, i don't seem to be able to import or link to a table of our geography hierarchy and dissolve the polygons by these fields.

Is this best achieved by importing CSV or linking to db etc?

our geo hierarchy:

```
Disrict, Ward, Neighbourhood, PC Sector
11, 11A, 11A15, AA1 1 etc.
```

Comment: QGIS can both join and dissolve. Please provide the steps you are taking - with screenshots - and where exactly you get stuck.